# ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC react.js template and identity

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

Is it possible to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identities` in a SPA project with react.js? The template in Visual Studio 2017 only offers a No Authentication option. If you can not use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, what other options are there? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer4 with AspNetCore.Identities is solution for SPA applications.

Answer (score 0):

Use ReactJs.Net - https://reactjs.net.

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var result = await drw.GetAllCompanysAsync();
            return View(result);
        }
```

in view

```
@model IEnumerable<Company>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Абоненты";
}
Html.React("Application", new
{
    initialData = Model,
    url = Url.Action("GetCompanyHeatPerDay", ,
    submitUrl = Url.Action("AddComment"),
}, containerId: "app")


<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/app.jsx")"></script>

Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

all view logic in app.jsx